# Angular electron typeorm not found module after electron-builder in production

Tags: angular, exception, electron, typeorm, node-sqlite3

I'm a novice in angular, electron and I clone a project with a good base to do it. But after building the app with electron-builder, I have this error :

Uncaught exception : Cannot find module './src/app/core/models/driver.schema'
Require stack : '....../release/mac/eas3-desktop.app/Content/resources/app.asar/main.js'

There is my code :

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';
import { Between, Connection, createConnection, getConnection, getConnectionManager } from 'typeorm';
import { Driver } from './src/app/core/models/driver.schema';
import { Patient } from './src/app/core/models/patient.schema';
import { Evenement } from './src/app/core/models/evenement.schema';
import { Place } from './src/app/core/models/place.schema';
import { Authentification } from './src/app/core/models/auth.schema';

let win: BrowserWindow = null;
const args = process.argv.slice(1),
  serve = args.some(val => val === '--serve');

async function createWindow(): Promise<BrowserWindow> {

  console.log("DIRNAME : " + __dirname)
  var connection = null
  try {
     connection = await createConnection({
      name: "connection",
      type: 'sqlite',
      synchronize: false,
      logging: true,
      logger: 'simple-console',
      database: './src/assets/data/database.sqlite',
      entities: [ Evenement, Driver, Patient, Place, Authentification],
      // migrations: [
      //   "../src/migration/*{.ts,.js}"
      // ],
      // cli: {
      //   migrationsDir: "../src/migration"
      // },
      // migrationsRun: true,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('[EXCEPTION WHILE TERMINATING APPLICATION CONTEXT]', e);
     // If AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError occurs, return already existent connection
     if (e.name === "AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError") {
      const existentConn = getConnectionManager().get("connection");
      connection = existentConn;
   }
  }
  
    await connection.query('PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF');
    await connection.synchronize();
    await connection.query('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON');
 
  const eventRepo = connection.getRepository(Evenement);
  const driverRepo = connection.getRepository(Driver);
  const patientRepo = connection.getRepository(Patient);
  const placeRepo = connection.getRepository(Place);
  const authRepo = connection.getRepository(Authentification);

  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: (serve) ? true : false,
      contextIsolation: false,  // false if you want to run 2e2 test with Spectron
      enableRemoteModule: true // true if you want to run 2e2 test  with Spectron or use remote module in renderer context (ie. Angular)
    },
  });
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  if (serve) {

    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
      electron: require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/electron`)
    });
    win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');

  } else {
    win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));
  }


  // -------------------------- AUTHENTIFICATION --------------------------
  ipcMain.on('get-auth-by-identifiant', async (event: any, _identifiant: string) => {
    try {
      event.returnValue = await authRepo.findOne({ where: { identifiant: _identifiant } });

    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
```

Can someone could help me understand why please ?

My project directory (main files) is :

```
----src 
    |__ app
         |__ core
               |__ models
                     |__ driver.schema.ts
                     |__ driver.schema.js (generated)
                     |__ driver.schema.js.map (generated)
    |__assets
    |__ index.html
    |__ main.ts
---- angular.json
---- electron-builder.json
---- main.ts
---- package.json
---- tsconfig.json
```

The package.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular-electron",
  "version": "9.0.3",
  "description": "Angular 11 with Electron (Typescript + SASS + Hot Reload)",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron",
  "author": {
    "name": "Maxime GRIS",
    "email": "maxime.gris@gmail.com"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular 11",
    "electron",
    "nodejs",
    "typescript",
    "spectron",
    "eslint",
    "sass",
    "windows",
    "mac",
    "linux"
  ],
  "main": "./main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p electron:serve ng:serve",
    "build": "npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build --base-href ./",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve -c web -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on tcp:4200 && npm run electron:serve-tsc && npx electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:dev && npx electron .",
    "electron:build": "npm run compile && build:prod && electron-builder build",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "test:watch": "ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run build:prod && cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json' mocha --timeout 300000 --require ts-node/register e2e/**/*.e2e.ts",
    "version": "conventional-changelog -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0 && git add CHANGELOG.md",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0",
    "@angular/localize": "11.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "11.0.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "12.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "8.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "6.1.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.28.22",
    "angular-randomcolor": "1.0.3",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "6.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "date-fns": "2.19.0",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.9",
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "2.3.1",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "ngx-electron": "2.2.0",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "10.12.4",
    "tooltip.js": "1.3.3",
    "typeorm": "0.2.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "10.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1100.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "0.8.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "0.8.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "0.8.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "0.8.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "0.8.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/mocha": "8.0.4",
    "@types/node": "12.12.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "4.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.7.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.1.1",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "cross-env": "7.0.2",
    "electron": "11.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "22.9.1",
    "electron-reload": "1.5.0",
    "eslint": "7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.8",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "6.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-electron": "6.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "mocha": "8.2.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "spectron": "13.0.0",
    "ts-node": "9.1.0",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "wait-on": "5.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.7",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.13.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the directories that you got on your project, in particular if you got everything in `models` directory

Comment: Don't know if it's a typing error but your `driver` model is named with an `s` in your directory but not when you import it on your code. Moreover, where are `patient`, `evenement`, `place` and `auth` schemas on your `models` directory ? If you don't have it and if the `s` of your driver schema is actually the error, you will have other errors when your code will try to import those schemas

Comment: Yes it's a typing error... I did not add petient, evenement end place but it's the same that driver.schema.xxx

Comment: Can you share the github link, have you change some things on the original project ?

Comment: I just add a lot of dependencies. Yes the link is : https://github.com/Thessalene/EASapp.git.  chek rework/full_calendar_version

Comment: I can run, build my app but not package it because main.ts doesn't find my entities file. I think it's due to my paths but I don't understand how it works after build in prod and run electron-builder.